# Flat Rate and Table Rate

Tags: shipping, catalog, table, flat

I have Flat rate shipping as the standard for all of my products $6.95, but I have a category that needs to be $14.95 because it is a tube and cost more to ship.  How can I make $14.95 the default for that category only, and hide the Flat rate.

Right now my customers see both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use table rates and make the products belonging to that certain category a heavier weight therefore invoking the higher price?

Comment: we have over 3000 products and our season begins now.  It is only for one category

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to create a custom shipping method in order to achieve this then. It's not too difficult to do this overall, you'll just need to examine the cart contents and ascertain if any of those products belong to the category in question  - if so give the higher price. This guide is a good starting point for creating bespoke shipping methods: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Comment: Now, I have the radio button Flat Rate $0.00 and Express delivery $12.30 and $14.95.  I don't want clients to choose (Flat Rate) but it is still an option.

Comment: You'll just need to put a conditional in the collectRates method to prevent the flat rate from showing if the any of the cart products belong to the category in question.

Comment: sorry, can you give me an example of an conditional to use?